# Opening a bootstrap5 dropdown programmatically only works in the browser's dev console, not in vanilla JS code

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I tried to open a Bootstrap5 dropdown when clicking a link in my web app. I tried dispatching events and using the bootstrap Dropdown classes, both without success. The code of both approaches works, when I run it in the developers console (Firefox & Chromium).

I stripped everything but bootstrap and wrote this micro website to make sure nothing else interferes with the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function test() {
      document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton1").click();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This is the dropdown example from the official bootstrap5 docs -->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Now the button, that should trigger a click on the dropdown -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Open Dropdown</button>
</body>

</html>
```

It's not working, but when I run

```
document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton1").click();
```

in the dev console, the dropdown opens.

Comment: fixed a typo in the code

Comment: Can't understand your question, can you clarify what you want to achieve and what issue did you ran into?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do this. It doesn't sound like a good UX practice.

Comment: You're right, but it's a requirement. There's an introductory help text on the website that asks the user to pick a species to calculate population trends for. When you hover above that text it highlights the dropdown, but my boss thinks it's a good idea to be able to click on that text to open the dropdown. I spent hours to find the solution I posted below, but that's the only thing that does the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @Quentin for the hint with the autoclose options. I still don't understand why the click event works in the developers console, but not in the script on the website.

However I managed to solve the problem with this hacky approach:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function test(){
  const elm = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton1");
  //  this disables the auto closing
  elm.setAttribute("data-bs-auto-close", "false");
  //  now open the dropdown
  new bootstrap.Dropdown(elm).show();
  //  restore the original state
  elm.removeAttribute("data-bs-auto-close");
  //  recreate the dropdown to apply the original state.
  //  without the timeout it does not work (it's not opening).
  setTimeout(() => {
    new bootstrap.Dropdown(elm);
  }, 10);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This is the dropdown example from the official bootstrap5 docs -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Now the button, that should trigger a click on the dropdown -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Open Dropdown</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This makes it possible to open the dropdown by clicking another element and keep the original behavior of the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the button moves the focus to the button, so the JavaScript runs, triggers the drop down to open, then the focus moves to the button.

The drop down menu is designed to close when it loses the focus, so when the focus moves to the button, it closes again (and this happens so quickly that it doesn't appear to open in the first place).

You can use the [autoClose](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior) option to change that behaviour.

Comment: While it works to change the attribute `data-bs-auto-close`, it changes the default behavior of the dropdown. You still need some extra code to make it work like it should, but that's pointing in the right direction!